# Header Location with variable

Tags: codeigniter

How to go with this url localhost/pitch/action/task/1 ?
1 = pitch id
please answer this. thank you

this is my code controller.

```
public function insert_task(){

    $this->load->model("save");

    $data['pitch_id'] = $this->input->post('pitch');
    $data['date'] = $this->input->post('date');
    $data['name'] = $this->input->post('name');
    $data['description'] = $this->input->post('description');

    $task = $this->save->insert_task_to_db($data);

    if($task){
        header('location:'.base_url()."action/task".$this->index());
    }
}
```

Comment: use `redirect('action/tast'.$id)` codeigniter has a built in function for that http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Comment: Just use `redirect('controller/methodname/params')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
redirect('action/task/'.$this->index(),'refresh');
```

this code will reload the page and redirect to the desired url.

Please let me know if you face any problem.

Answer (score 0):

codeigniter provides [redirect](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html), like:

```
redirect( base_url() . 'action/task/' . $this->index() );
```